# I am using Putty to run and compile vue js + laravel app on Godaddy VPS. Changes are not taking effect

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, vps

I am using Putty to run and compile vue js + laravel app on Godaddy VPS. Changes are not taking effect.

I have Laravel + Vue.js App on VPS.
When I make changes in code, I am running following command in Putty.

npm run dev
npm run watch

Changes are not being applied. Even when it shows all modules built successfully.

npm run watch should apply changes in code.
In local environment using wamp it works

Comment: Could you try with npm run watch-poll

Comment: It didn't change anything, I just tried. Thanks @WisdmLabs.

Answer (score 0):

oh, have you tried laravel cached views clear??
`php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Oh, that's sad. Could it be your browser don't refreshing properly? Try another browser...