# compilation successfully while running the command npm run watch on compute engine but no any changing effects

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Compilation successfully while running the command **npm run watch** on compute engine ubuntu terminal but no changing effects. I use the Larave+Vue project hosted on the Ubuntu VM instance on GCP. I search much time for this issue but not able to find any solution. I found a similar problem on StackOverflow but there is no answer to solve my problem. Please check the link below:

[I am using Putty to run and compile vue js + laravel app on Godaddy VPS. Changes are not taking effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018221/i-am-using-putty-to-run-and-compile-vue-js-laravel-app-on-godaddy-vps-changes)

Please help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `npm run watch-poll` instead, on certain systems `watch` doesn't trigger changes but `wacth-poll` will periodically checks (polls) for changes.

Comment: I also tried `npm run watch-poll` but got the same issue :( . Thanks for the reply :)